# Customização Carousel

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Olá a todos sou iniciante em Bootstrap, e estou desenvolvendo um carousel no boostrap, só que ao invés de mostrar apenas uma imagem gostaria que mostrasse 3, como na imagem abaixo. Como que eu poderia estar fazendo isso

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código

```
   <div class="container">
    <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="Primeiro Slide">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="Segundo Slide">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="Terceiro Slide">
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <img src="img/seta_e.png">
                <span class="sr-only">Anterior</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <img src="img/seta_l.png">
                <span class="sr-only">Próximo</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sei que não tem a ver com a pergunta, mas eu iria fazer com o [owlcarousel](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/basic.html). É responsivo, altamente customizável, pode aplicar efeitos de transição, editar e colocar quantos itens deseja, definir tamanho...

Comment: Aqui tem um exemplo usando *Bootstrap 3*, https://www.bootply.com/94444

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vc pode colocar 3 imagens no *container* e usar classes do Bootstrap como `d-none` `d-flex` para ir fazendo a responsividade. No desktop vc mostra 3, no tablet 2 e no smartphone 1 por vez?

Segue um exemplo simples que fiz seguindo esse conceito. As vezes pode ser útil para vc.

```css
.carousel-item-next, .carousel-item-prev, .carousel-item.active {
    display: flex !important;
}
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img class="w-100 m-md-1" src="https://www.placecage.com/350/150" alt="Primeiro Slide">
                <img class="d-none d-md-flex w-100 m-0 m-md-1" src="https://www.placecage.com/351/150" alt="Primeiro Slide">
                <img class="d-none d-lg-flex w-100 m-md-1" src="https://www.placecage.com/352/150" alt="Primeiro Slide">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="w-100 m-md-1" src="https://www.placecage.com/350/150" alt="Primeiro Slide">
                <img class="d-none d-md-flex w-100 m-md-1" src="https://www.placecage.com/351/150" alt="Primeiro Slide">
                <img class="d-none d-lg-flex w-100 m-md-1" src="https://www.placecage.com/352/150" alt="Primeiro Slide">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="w-100 m-md-1" src="https://www.placecage.com/350/150" alt="Primeiro Slide">
                <img class="d-none d-md-flex w-100 m-md-1" src="https://www.placecage.com/351/150" alt="Primeiro Slide">
                <img class="d-none d-lg-flex w-100 m-md-1" src="https://www.placecage.com/352/150" alt="Primeiro Slide">
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <img src="img/seta_e.png">
                <span class="sr-only">Anterior</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <img src="img/seta_l.png">
                <span class="sr-only">Próximo</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```